# How can I prevent rsync replacing symbolic links with new directories in the target directory hierarchy?

Tags: rsync, symbolic-link

I am using [rsync(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to synchronize files between a source area and a target area, where the *target* directory hierarchy contains symbolic links.

When a source directory has the same name and relative path as a symbolic link in the target area, then rsync *replaces* the symbolic link with the copied source directory and all its contents. I want rsync to instead leave the symbolic link intact, and only copy files that would have been copied had the symbolic link been a real directory.

I'm currently using `-Cvrtp` options to rsync. I'm aware of the `--links` option, but that appears to relate only to symbolic links in the source area.

Is there a way to obtain the behaviour I'm looking for with rsync?

Answer (score 17):

No sooner had I asked the question than I discovered the answer.

In fact, `rsync` has the option

```
-K / --keep-dirlinks
```

which appears to be exactly what I'm looking for.